# How to change position of label input form django

Tags: django, forms, label

I am using form with django, I succeeded to create the form, but I don't know how to change position of label of my input to the right, because by default label is in the center.
This is an example of I have : [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14RfO.png)

code :

```
input= forms.CharField(
    label="myLabel",
    required=True,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','maxlength':'30'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you render the form fields individually at the template level:

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are using 'form-control' just in your input field, but this class is to use in the entire form. Using as you did you're just applying the features only in your input field

I suggest you use [django-bootstrap4](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap4/) library to render your forms. and select a class for your label as showed in the documentation [here](https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-label)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedbacks, I fixed the issue by adding  myLabel<\div>